# In decorator function, Is there a way to apply the session used by decorator wrapper function to the repository code?

Tags: python, pymongo, decorator

First of all, I'm so sorry to write an ambiguous title.

My situation is like below.

I wanted to use Transactional decorator (like @Transactional in Spring)

But in order to use transaction in PyMongo,

it need to use the session of wrapper function like Repository function(mongo_user_repository.save()).

(docs - https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/client_session.html)

So, Is there any way to get session of wrapper function in Service functions or some other way to use transactional decorator in Service functions?

I made decorator,

```
class MongoDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__client = MongoClient(
            DB_URL,
            tlsCAFile=certifi.where()
        )

    def close(self):
        self.__client.close()

    def transactional(self, origin_func):
        def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
            with self.__client.start_session() as session:
                with session.start_transaction():
                    return origin_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper_func
```

And wanted to use like this in service code.

```
class UserService:
    def __init__(
        self,
        mongo_user_repository: MongoUsersRepository,
    ):
        self.__mongo_user_repository: MongoUsersRepository = mongo_user_repository

    @mongodb.transactional
    def save(self, user_create_request: UserCreateRequestDto):
        mongo_user = MongoUsers.from_dto(user_create_request=user_create_request)

        self.__mongo_user_repository.save(
            mongo_user=mongo_user,
            session=session
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `mongodb.transactional` call the wrapped function with `session` as an additional argument:

```
def transactional(self, origin_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        with self.__client.start_session() as session:
            with session.start_transaction():
                return origin_func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func
```

so that the decorated service function can take `session` as an argument:

```
@mongodb.transactional
def save(self, user_create_request: UserCreateRequestDto, session):
    mongo_user = MongoUsers.from_dto(user_create_request=user_create_request)

    self.__mongo_user_repository.save(
        mongo_user=mongo_user,
        session=session
    )
```